# Java Completable Future - better to have loop of futures or future of a loop?

Tags: java, asynchronous

I need to run a method hundreds of times for different data, at various points of the method its waiting on data from DB or response from web call. It seems to make sense to run this asynchronously so that processing can occur during wait times, however I must wait on the result returning from all the runs before moving on, my question is what's the difference between:

1. Creating a single completableFuture and running the loop within this. Then ensuring the completableFuture has finished before moving on.
   OR
2. Creating a loop of completable futures each with a single method call, then using allOf to then wait on the last one finishing.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is mot clear. Do you have hundreds of separate tasks that each produce one result? Do the tasks depend on another or can they each run separately? Does the order in which they execute matter?

Answer (score 1):

Running the for loop inside `CompletableFututre` is not a good idea because that for loop will be executed synchronously. Having multiple `CompletableFuture` that call the same method multiple times is a better idea but you should make sure that all methods that are blocking are executed asynchronously.

```
List<CompletableFuture> futures = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3")
        .stream()
        .map(a -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> method1(),
                executorService))
        .map(a -> a.thenCompose(b -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> dbcall(b),
                dbExecutorService)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This way `method1` and `dbcall` are executed on different `ExecutorService` and blocking call to DB on `dbcall` method in `dbExecutorService` does not lead to threads being exhausted in `executorService`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, should the completableFuture be as close to the wait as possible? My method in question does a bit of set up, a few DB checks then calls a web service that takes a few seconds. Its really the webservice delay thats the issue, so should the CF be over just the web call or can i benefit from having it over the whole method?

Comment: If the webservice is the real problem you can  call your method similar to something I have called `method1` in my sample code. This will  make things better. But if it does not solve the problem you can put `dbcall` in another `CompletableFuture` and call it similar to calling `dbcall` in my sample code.

Answer (score 1):

## Project Loom

This work will be simpler when [*Project Loom*](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main) technology arrives in Java.

This project is adding virtual threads ([fibers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_(computer_science))) to the Java concurrency toolbox. Many running virtual threads can be mapped to run on top of platform/kernel threads. When a virtual thread blocks, it is “parked”, and another virtual thread is assigned to execute on the platform/kernel thread. This switching between virtual threads is done very quickly, making **thread-blocking extremely cheap** in terms of its impact on performance.

Virtual threads are also extremely cheap in terms of its use of memory. Whereas platform/kernel threads are allocated rather large stack sizes no matter the need, virtual threads have a stack that expands as needed… and shrinks when no longer needed.

Virtual threads promise to eliminate the risks of using thread pools. Every thread is fresh with its own [`ThreadLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) values.

Experimental builds based on early-access Java 17 are [available now](http://jdk.java.net/loom/). The Project Loom team is soliciting feedback.

### `AutoCloseable`

In Loom, the [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) interface becomes [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html). So we can use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax. The flow-of-control leaves the `try` block only after all submitted tasks are done/failed/canceled. When leaving the `try` block, the executor service is automatically closed.

### No need for `CompletableFuture`

You can simply launch many virtual threads, millions even, and let them run. Most of the need for the many methods on [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) evaporates. For more info, see the more recent presentations and interviews with Ron Pressler of Oracle.

We can simply spin off all the tasks on virtual threads, collecting [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) objects along the way. Then simply wait for all those tasks to finish.

### Example code

Establish an `ExecutorService` instance. Submit to that executor service your `Callable` tasks. Capture the returned `Future` objects to track successful completion.

```java
int countTasks = 1_000 ;  // Number of tasks to spin off into threads.
List < Future < YourResultClass > > futures = new ArrayList <>( countTasks );

try (
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadExecutor() ;
)
{
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < countTasks ; i++ )
    {
        // Submit a Callable object to the executor service.
        Future < YourResultClass > future = executorService.submit( ( ) -> {
            // The work to be done in each thread.
            YourResultClass yourResultObject = … ;
            return yourResultObject;
        } );
        futures.add( future );
    }
}
// At this point, flow-of-control blocks until all submitted tasks are done/failed/canceled. 
// After this point, the executor service is automatically closed.
```

After the work is done, we can example the collected `Future` objects to verify results.

```java
// Report on all the futures, all the results of the thousand tasks.
for ( Future < YourResultClass > future : futures )
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println(
                "future.isDone(): " + ( future.isDone() + " | future.isCompletedNormally(): " + future.isCompletedNormally() + " | future.isCancelled():  " + future.isCancelled() + " | result: " + future.get().toString() )
        );
    }
    catch ( InterruptedException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch ( ExecutionException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

### Example app

Here is a complete app. Not what I would do in production of course, but it makes for a decent demonstration I hope.

This code spins off a thousand tasks. Each task makes a REST call to ask Wikipedia for a random page. The contents of that page are then written to a [H2 database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)). We collect the [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) objects returned when submitting `Callable` tasks to the executor service, and we examine those after the work is done.

I configured an in-memory database, but you could just as well put the database in storage.

For simplicity, I defined my `WikipediaPage` class as a `record`. This [new feature in Java 16](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/359) is a brief way to write a class whose main purpose is to immutable and transparently carry data. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`. Not important to this Answer; you could just as well use a conventional class.

```java
package work.basil.example.loopingfutures;

import org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.sql.*;
import java.time.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( Runtime.version() );
        System.out.println( Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() );
        App app = new App();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        DataSource dataSource = this.configureDataSource();
        this.destroyDatabaseContents( dataSource );
        this.createDatabase( dataSource );
        this.work( dataSource , 1_000 );
        this.dumpTable( dataSource );
    }

    private DataSource configureDataSource ( )
    {
        JdbcDataSource dataSource = Objects.requireNonNull( new JdbcDataSource() );  // Implementation of `DataSource` bundled with H2.
        dataSource.setURL( "jdbc:h2:mem:looping_loom_example_db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" ); // Set `DB_CLOSE_DELAY` to `-1` to keep in-memory database in existence after connection closes.
        dataSource.setUser( "scott" );
        dataSource.setPassword( "tiger" );
        return dataSource;
    }

    private void destroyDatabaseContents ( DataSource dataSource )
    {
        try (
                Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection() ;
        )
        {
            String sql = """
                         DROP TABLE IF EXISTS wikipedia_page_
                         ;
                         """;
            System.out.println( "sql:  \n" + sql );
            try ( Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ; )
            {
                stmt.execute( sql );
            }
        }
        catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void createDatabase ( final DataSource dataSource )
    {
        try (
                Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection() ;
        )
        {
            String sql = """
                         CREATE TABLE wikipedia_page_
                            ( 
                               id_ UUID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY , 
                               url_ VARCHAR NOT NULL ,
                               content_ CLOB NOT NULL ,
                               when_fetched_ TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL , 
                               row_created_ TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() 
                             )
                         ;
                         """;
            System.out.println( "sql:  \n" + sql );
            try ( Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ; )
            {
                stmt.execute( sql );
            }
        }
        catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void work ( final DataSource dataSource , final int countPagesToFetchFromWikipedia )
    {
        List < Future < WikipediaPage > > futures = new ArrayList <>( countPagesToFetchFromWikipedia );
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        try (
                ExecutorService executorService = newVirtualThreadExecutor() ;
        )
        {
            for ( int i = 0 ; i < countPagesToFetchFromWikipedia ; i++ )
            {
                // Submit a Callable object to the executor service.
                Future < WikipediaPage > future = executorService.submit( ( ) -> {
                    // To meet Wikipedia's limit of 200 requests per second, let's throttle by sleeping the worker thread.
                    try {Thread.sleep( Duration.ofMillis( 100 ) ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                    WikipediaPage page = this.fetchPage();
                    this.persistPage( dataSource , page );
                    return page;
                } );
                futures.add( future );
            }
        }
        // At this point, flow-of-control blocks until all submitted tasks are done/failed/canceled. The executor service is automatically closed.
        Duration duration = Duration.ofNanos( System.nanoTime() - start );
        System.out.println( "duration = " + duration + " for a count of " + countPagesToFetchFromWikipedia );

        // Report on all the futures, all the results of the thousand tasks.
        for ( Future < WikipediaPage > future : futures )
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println(
                        "future.isDone(): " + ( future.isDone() + " | future.isCompletedNormally(): " + future.isCompletedNormally() + " | future.isCancelled():  " + future.isCancelled() + " | result: " + future.get().toString() )
                );
            }
            catch ( InterruptedException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch ( ExecutionException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println( "INFO - End of `work` method. Message # 26893b25-b09c-40d5-8cee-60e6a1d53852." );
    }

    private WikipediaPage fetchPage ( )
    {
        WikipediaPage page = null;  // To be returned.
        HttpClient client =
                HttpClient
                        .newBuilder()
                        .followRedirects( HttpClient.Redirect.NORMAL )
                        .build();
        HttpRequest request =
                HttpRequest
                        .newBuilder()
                        .uri( URI.create( "https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/random/summary" ) )
                        .build();
        try
        {
            HttpResponse < String > response = client.send( request , HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString() );
            OffsetDateTime whenFetched = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC );
            URI uri = response.uri();
            String content = response.body();

            System.out.println( "response = " + response );
            System.out.println( "content = " + content );

            page = new WikipediaPage( UUID.randomUUID() , uri.toString() , content , whenFetched );
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Objects.requireNonNull( page );
    }

    private void persistPage ( final DataSource dataSource , final WikipediaPage wikipediaPage )
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull( dataSource );
        Objects.requireNonNull( wikipediaPage );
        String sql = """
                     INSERT INTO wikipedia_page_ ( id_ , url_ , content_ , when_fetched_ )
                     VALUES ( ? , ? , ? , ? )
                     ;
                     """;
        System.out.println( "sql:  \n" + sql );
        try (
                Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection() ;
                PreparedStatement pstmt = Objects.requireNonNull( conn ).prepareStatement( sql ) ;
        )
        {
            pstmt.setObject( 1 , wikipediaPage.id );
            pstmt.setString( 2 , wikipediaPage.url );
            pstmt.setString( 3 , wikipediaPage.content );
            pstmt.setObject( 4 , wikipediaPage.whenFetched );

            int countRowsAffected = pstmt.executeUpdate();
            if ( countRowsAffected != 1 )
            {
                System.out.println( "ERROR - Failed to insert row. Message # 4c3503d9-8cad-4e21-a625-c58054d9ca78." );
            }
        }
        catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void dumpTable ( final DataSource dataSource )
    {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM wikipedia_page_ ;";
        System.out.println( "sql:  \n" + sql );
        try (
                Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection() ;
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql ) ;
        )
        {
            while ( rs.next() )
            {
                //Retrieve by column name
                UUID id = rs.getObject( "id_" , UUID.class );
                String url = rs.getString( "url_" );
                String content = rs.getString( "content_" );
                OffsetDateTime whenFetched = rs.getObject( "when_fetched_" , OffsetDateTime.class );

                WikipediaPage wp = new WikipediaPage( id , url , content , whenFetched );
                System.out.println( "wp = " + wp );
            }
        }
        catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    record WikipediaPage(UUID id , String url , String content , OffsetDateTime whenFetched)
    {
        @Override
        public String toString ( )
        {
            // Omitting the `content` field for brevity.
            return "WikipediaPage{ " +
                    "id=" + id +
                    " | url='" + url + '\'' +
                    " | whenFetched=" + whenFetched +
                    " }";
        }
    }
}
```

### Results

All of these results are for 1,000 tasks. Run on a Mac mini (2018) 3 GHz Intel Core i5 with 32 gigs of RAM, macOS Mojave 10.14.6, Java 17-loom+2-42 assigned maximum memory of 8 gigs (8589934592).

When running with `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`, takes 7 minutes.

When running with `Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 10 )`, takes 1 minute.

When running with `Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 100 )`, takes half a minute.

When running with `Executors.newVirtualThreadExecutor()`, takes a quarter minute.